# test variable title with ID - selenium ide

Tags: css, unit-testing, testing, xpath, selenium

using selenium IDE i testing my site

in some pages i have a link with variable ID

ex : ( http://yourorder.com/135046 )

every time user click on this link site take him to process page number (135046)
so this number always changing ( variable )

so i can't use

```
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>link=yourorder.com/135046</td>
</tr>
```

what i can do ?
help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you locate the element by this xpath:

```
"//td[contains(text(), 'link=yourorder.com')]"
```

Comment: i can't use the link, because it contains id , therefore i will not be able to use it with other items which has different IDs --- i used click > //html/body/div[6]/div[3]/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/a -- thanks a lot Nora

Comment: you're welcome, if you give me a sample page of your website I can try and see if I can come up with a nicer/cleaner xpath for you.

Answer (score 1):

There is various other options in for selection of target in **SELENIUM IDE**.

Sequence of selecting target value is following:

1. **ID**
2. **NAME**
3. **LINK**
4. **DOM**
5. **CSS**
6. **XPATH**

Structure of **XPATH** is `//html tag[@property='value']`

So you can try with these.

Comment: xpath is the easiest option for selecting of target of any command in selenium ide.

if you got your answer then do not forget to accept my answer....:)

Comment: i can't use id or name or link , because in my special case they will contains id , therefore i will not be able to use it with other items which has different IDs --- i used click > //html/body/div[6]/div[3]/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/a -- thanks a lot naveen

Answer (score 0):

```
click > //html/body/div[6]/div[3]/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/a
```

thanks everyone